# Relative layout template has problems displaying design

Tags: android

if i change the default layout to relative layout in android studio. it will show "design editor is unavailable until a successful build" how to solve this ?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, to state the obvious: do a successful build.

Comment: You need to rebuild your project afterwards, which might be tricky with error(s) in the MainActivity file

Comment: rebuild your project

Comment: If I use constraint layout, the design is working well.

Comment: How to rebuild the project pls help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments rebuild your project. Look at top panel select Build -> Clean Project. Wait while cleaning will be finished(Progress bar in the bottom panel). Then Build -> Rebuild Project.